# How can I set permissions for editing my own user data but not the others' data?

Tags: user-permissions, gentics-mesh

In my project I have two roles/groups: admin and user. Admins can add and edit users, users can only read the data.
How can I achieve that a user can edit its own data (like password, name, ...) but not the others? Since I can only add permissions to roles, I would need a individual role for every user. Is there another way to solve this?
Kind regards
Nils

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you would need to create a dedicated group and role for that single user. We have already encountered the same limitation and are working on a long-term solution. One option would be to allow user roles. This way no dedicated group would be needed.

Related issues:

- https://github.com/gentics/mesh/issues/48
- https://github.com/gentics/mesh/issues/140